# Take active class and replicate in other divs

Tags: jquery

I have a slideshow using jQuery.fullPage.js. I'm adding a background color to various slides and I am trying to grab the background color from whatever slide is active and add that as a class to the slide controls of the slideshow.

My jQuery for doing that is:

```
$('.controlArrow').on('click', function () {
      $('.slide').each(function () {
          if ($(this).hasClass('black', 'active')) {
              $('.black.active').closest('.section').children('.controlArrow').addClass('black').removeClass('gray');
          } else {
              if ($(this).hasClass('gray', 'active')) {
                  $('.gray.active').closest('.section').children('.controlArrow').addClass('gray').removeClass('black');
              }
          }

      });
  });
```

The problem is the classes added to the arrow don't actually mimic what's in the active slide. So if I have:

```
<div class="slide black active">
```

my slide controls might look like this:

```
<div class="controlArrow prev gray"></div>
```

I've also tried:

```
 $('.controlArrow').click(function() {
```

but that did not seem to help. I have a feeling my logic is messed up but i'm not seeing it.

I have a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/Jxh9L/).

***Adding a screen capture for clarity.***

[image]

Comment: sorry can you explain again what you are looking for

Comment: @ArunPJohny - I've added a screen capture to clarify. Whatever color is active in `.slide` should also be the same color in `.controlArrow`. Right now it's arbitrary.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YGLrE/5/

Comment: If you view with web inspector, once you click on the arrows, the class for `.controlArrow` does not match up with what's `.active` in `.slide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var pepe = $.fn.fullpage({
        'css3': true,
        "verticalCentered": true
    });
    var colors = ['gray', 'black'], regex = new RegExp(colors.join('|'));
    $('.controlArrow').on('click', function () {
        var classes = $('.slide.active').prop('className');
        var color = classes.match(regex)[0];
        $('.controlArrow').removeClass(colors.join(' ')).addClass(color)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YGLrE/)

Comment: It does not seem to be matching up. If you view with web inspector, once you start clicking on the arrows, the class for `.controlArrow` does not match up with what's `.active` in `.slide`

Comment: yes, that's nice! Thank you! I like the way you did this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's working and adding the class you want to the controls. If you're trying to put the color of the slider in to the controls, you need to controls de border-color of the control, not it background-color, that's why you don't see the colors changing.

Comment: I've added a screen capture above to clarify. Whatever color is active in `.slide` should also be the same color in `.controlArrow`. Right now it's arbitrary.